# AD FS SSO Force Login for certain users or OU

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, adfs4.0

Can an application have SSO only for users of a particular AD group and force users to manually enter their credentials for users not in that AD group?

Answer (score -1):

ADFS provides the ability to authenticate.

You can restrict this ability in a number of ways e.g. have to be a member of a group, have to be an internal user etc.

But that is authenticate or not authenticate.

SSO is different. IE has IWA set by default. Users inside the domain get SSO. Users outside the domain don't. But that's a browser function, not an ADFS one.